# What is the correct way to define a CSS variable that will inherit from a prior value (of the same name) but have a sensible default?

Tags: css, css-variables

It seems to me that the best way to use CSS variables in many cases is to have them default to a pre-existing value but have a sensible default.

E.g. instead of writing:

```
:host {
  --background: white;
  --color: black;
}
```

You should be able to write:

```
:host {
  --background: var(--background, white);
  --color: var(--color, black);
}
```

This would allow settings to flow through from "above" for consistency, but allow a component to render nicely in isolation.

Weirdly, this doesn't work even though Chrome (at least) suggests it does work in the inspector.

E.g. if I define a component with `--error-color: var(--error-color, crimson)` then in the inspector the `--error-color` is shown as having a crimson swatch (yay!) but the color doesn't actually get used by CSS rules.

As far as I can tell, this definition is correct, the inspector recognizes it, but it doesn't actually work.

So, should this work or is it just wrong? Is there a right way to accomplish this?

Comment: you cannot define a variable by itself

Comment: Do you have any basis for this statement? It does not violate the specification in any way AFAICT. Similarly, --a: var(--b, red); --b: var(--a); is totally well-defined but also doesn't work.

Comment: The answer here suggests that cyclic references generate an internal runtime error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50861664/css-variable-inherit-from-same-name?rq=2

It's a bit odd since the concept of a = a + 1 or a = a || default_value work just fine in most dynamic programming languages.

Comment: CSS is a set of declarations not consecutive instructions than run one after another.

Comment: Yes, but --foo: var(--foo, black) is a perfectly valid declaration. It makes just as much sense as --foo: var(--bar, black) since both look "above" themselves in the cascade for properties.

Comment: no one said the declaration is not valid. it's valid but "Invalid at computed value time". As I said, it's not a sequential running, they are declarations.  related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51660820/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/51603171/8620333)

Comment: a good read before you start hating CSS variables (they don't work like you think they should do): https://dev.to/afif/what-no-one-told-you-about-css-variables-553o#8-css-variables-are-not-c-variables

Comment: Thanks for your replies yeah it's pretty clear they don't work like they ought to on a given element).

The not sequential is fine, it still works for --foo = --bar where --bar is declared at the same point.

Comment: I should add that I *love* CSS variables and use them all the time, but I'm trying to minimize boilerplate and automate documentation.